# how to use textscan in matlab

Tags: matlab, textscan

i'm trying to inesrt the following text file into a matrix in matlab

[time.txt](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_eNjePEMqsgcWNVQjA3bW50UEU)

I tried to use 'textscan'

```
fileID = fopen('Uz10.txt');

Uz10=textscan(fileID,'%d');

fclose(fileID);
```

but alwayes got,

```
Undefined operator '*' for input arguments of type 'cell'.
```

can anybody gives me the right format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify you code this way:

1) by specifying `%s` as the `format`: in this case, `textscan` returns a `cellarray` of string

```
fileID = fopen('Uz10.txt');
% Uz10=textscan(fileID,'%d:%d');
Uz10=textscan(fileID,'%s');
fclose(fileID);
```

*Output*:

```
>> Uz10{1}

ans = 

    '0:00'
    '0:10'
    '0:20'
    '0:30'
     ...
```

2) by specifying `%d:%d` as the `format`: in this case, `textscan` returns a `(1x2) cellarray` of `int32` type containing the two digit of each row. Then you can concatenate them in order have a `(nx2)` matrix

```
fileID = fopen('Uz10.txt');
Uz10=textscan(fileID,'%d:%d');
% Uz10=textscan(fileID,'%s');
fclose(fileID);

t=[Uz10{1} Uz10{2}]
```

*Output*:

```
>> t=[Uz10{1} Uz10{2}]

t =

           0           0
           0          10
           0          20
           0          30
           ...        ...
```

If you want to manage the data as `time data` you can use the function [datetime](https://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetime.html).

For example (using the first of the above `format` to read the input file):

```
datetime(Uz10{1},'InputFormat','m:ss')
```

*Output*:

```
>> datetime(Uz10{1},'InputFormat','m:ss')

ans = 

   24-Sep-2017 00:00:00
   24-Sep-2017 00:00:10
   24-Sep-2017 00:00:20
   24-Sep-2017 00:00:30
   ...
```